# A layout with a image background isnt responding on size change

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a layout (`tab` from now on) wich has a background (204px x 54px).

I've set that `tab` to many sizes:
At the moment it's set to 70dp x 40dp:

[image]

As you can see, on the XML its displaying somehow like it should be viewed in the device, but when I run it, it ignores the width and the height, so it's being displayed as it is originally (probably takes width & height from the background image).

However, those `tabs` are placed inside a LinearLayout, so I inflate it several times and I add it into the `tabsContainer` layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

As you  can see, I've set a 40dp height and it's working. Its streching the `tab` layout BUT I also want to reduce the `tab`'s width. 
[image]

As you can see in the picture, the last one tab's width is kinda smaller because it's in the "end" of the `tabsContainer`.

Can you give me any tip?

**UPADTE**

Now my tab layout is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/inactiu_docs"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titlePestanya"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:text="Producto simple"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

And this is the code I'm using to inflate:

```
RelativeLayout pestanya = (RelativeLayout) this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pestanya_per_inflar, null);
```

I've tried to do it like:

```
RelativeLayout pestanya = (RelativeLayout) this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pestanya_per_inflar, tabsContainer);
```

But it's crashing with error:

> android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout

**SOLVED**
Use this when inflating:

```
inflate(R.layout.pestanya_per_inflar, tabsContainer, false);
```

And use the previous XML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent is a `LinearLayout`, then you should use `android:layout_width="0"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` on your tabs.

When you inflate, make sure you pass a parent.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: never inflate without passing a parent or you will lose your xml parameters ([LEARN MORE](https://plus.google.com/115236917399025801624/posts/FbKbxXUXBHn))

Comment: I've set weight and width to the ones you said, and it's still happening the same.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán can you update your post (with weight modification) and provide more code (like the inflate)?

Comment: I was not passing a parent when inflating. Let me do it and will feed you back. I've also updated my post with the xml code

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán did you try to `inflate(R.layout.pestanya_per_inflar, tabsContainer, false);`?

Comment: Wow, this did the trick. Thank you so much. There isn't any day that you don't learn a new thing, hah!

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán you should read this https://plus.google.com/115236917399025801624/posts/FbKbxXUXBHn